# Was King Théoden completely possessed by Saruman or did he retain at least a portion of his free will?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-two-towers

In the movie, King Théoden is apparently possessed by Saruman. However, to what degree he was possessed isn't obvious. Was he completely possessed or did he retain some of his free will?

Comment: Corrupted, I believe the text says. Hence why Wormtongue needed to keep convincing him of things rather than just commanding him to obey.

Answer (score 13):

In the films, it is suggested that King Théoden's mind was indeed imprisoned and enslaved by Sauron's and as such the amount of free will was quite limited, if any at all existed:

> The king’s mind is enslaved, it’s an old device of Saruman’s.
> <sub>[The Two Towers, Screenplay - Raindance.org](https://www.raindance.org/scripts/lotr-the-two-towers.pdf)</sub>

> ...whose mind is overthrown. Saruman’s hold over King Théoden is now very strong.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Later in the scene it is shown the Théoden for the most part simply repeats Wormtongue's words, and struggles as if he has no interest in doing so. He continues however to look for approval:

> WORMTONGUE (whispered to THÉODEN)
> He’s not welcome.
> THÉODEN (labored)
> Why should I welcome you, Gandalf Stormcrow?
>
> *He looks to WORMTONGUE for affirmation, who nods.*
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Finally, Gandalf describes Saruman's presence like a poison. Interestingly, he also seems to talk to Saruman as if he is directly there in Théoden's mind. This is further suggested by the use of "Théoden/Saruman" in the prompt for who is speaking:

> I will draw you, Saruman, as poison is drawn from a wound.
>
> THÉODEN/SARUMAN
> If I go, Théoden dies.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

In the books however, Théoden is shown to have some more free will, however that he trust heavily in Gríma's words and listens to him:

> *Too long have you sat in shadows and trusted to twisted tales and crooked promptings.*
> <sub>The Two Towers, Book 3, Chapter 7: Helm's Deep</sub>

The suggestion seems to be that through deceipt, Gríma was able to ensnare Théoden and convince him to do his bidding.

Comment: what I find interesting is Gandalf's comment that mind-enslavement is an 'old device' of Saruman's. Like - in the film we are given to believe that Gandalf trusted Saruman nearly implicitly until the moment Saruman revealed his intentions in Orthanc. In the Hobbit films, there isn't any real indication of distrust between the two. So - Gandalf is aware that Saruman has employed mind control before and up until now has been cool with it? "I must see the head of my order. He is both wise and powerful. Trust me Frodo, he'll know what to do." now *I* have questions..questions that need answering

Comment: If Saruman had used on, say, orcs or intelligent monsters in order to stop them in battle or prevent attacks on innocents, Gandalf may have seen that as an acceptable use.

Comment: In the book, it seemed like this was the one most identifiable instance where Gandalf (probably) utilized Narya.  Theoden had been gradually seduced into despair by Wormtongue, but Gandalf revives him by using what Cirdan describes as Narya's power: *For this is the Ring of Fire, and with it you may rekindle hearts in a world that grows chill.*

Comment: Saruman's power was his voice. So it is very possible he used it to turn hostilities into fear or friendliness, or to make somebody do their bidding by feeding them lies. Or simply persuading them. Or something like that.

Comment: Can you give the link for the scripts of the other movies as well  ?